# Why is the type of (.) head ((a -> [c]) -> a -> c)?

Tags: haskell

I have tried `:t (.) head` on GHCi and get result `(a -> [c]) -> a -> c`
I get very confuse about this. Could someone give me a hint to help me comprehend this?

For my own thinking, the result should be `([a] -> a -> c)-> a -> c`

Comment: Why do you think it should be `([a] -> a -> c) -> a -> c`?

Answer (score 8):

**hint**:

```
(.) head 
= \f   -> (.) head f
= \f   -> head . f 
= \f a -> head (f a)
```

once you have this the rest follows as this:

- `head :: [c] -> c`
- `f :: a -> b` - so as we do `head . f` we must have `b = [c]`

now the complete expression has

```
\     f              a        -> head (f a)
:: (a -> [c])     -> a        -> c
      ^ type of f    ^ the a     ^ result of head (f a)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
head     ::  [n] -> n
--   b ~ [n]  |     | c ~ n
--            |     |
(.)      ::  (b  -> c) -> (a ->  b ) -> a -> c

(.) head ::               (a -> [n]) -> a -> n

-- rename n to c:         (a -> [c]) -> a -> c
```

Comment: Thank you ,I'm newer of Haskell, further question is why head designated to ( b -> c ) ,but ( a -> b) ?

Comment: and if the question is succ . head , how do I improve it has type or error? Thank you

Comment: @Nostaglia Because that's the first argument to `(.)`.